# How to find Angle between a 2D and a 3D Vectors

Tags: vectors

Let:
$Let\ C = i+\sqrt3j\ and\ D = i+\frac{1}{\sqrt3}j+k$

Find angle between $C$ and $D$.

I know that to find the angle between two 2D vectors, you can use scalar multiplication which is:
$u\times v = ||u||\times ||v||\times \cos\theta$
However I am confused as to how I am supposed to approach this when it is a 2D and 3D vector.
I am assuming that the matrix form will be $(i,j,0), (i, j, k)$, with the 3rd value for the 2D being $0$, but I do not know to work upon this.

Comment: The vector $C=i+\sqrt{3}j$ isn't a 2D vector. It is whatever dimension the question is set in. Both could represent vectors in 9000D if needed. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Every 2D vector like $i + \sqrt{3}j$ is also a 3D vector, namely $i + \sqrt{3} j + 0 k$.
2. The scalar product is the other one: $v \cdot w = v_i w_i + v_j w_j + v_k w_k$, where $v = v_i i + v_j j + v_k k$, and similarly for $w$.
3. The rules in this case is $v \cdot w = \|v \|~ \|w\| ~\cos \theta$.

THat should get you going.

Comment: So in this case, $v\times w = 1+1+0$, and $||v|| = \sqrt(1+3+0)$ (likewise with ||w||). And then using that, find $\theta = \arctan (value)$

Comment: First, use "cdot" rather than "times", i.e., $v \cdot w$ rather than $v \times w$. And second, you'll find $\theta$ with $\theta = \arccos (value)$ rather than arctan.